# EC2 for handling demand spikes

Tags: amazon-ec2, scalability, load-balancing

I'm writing the backend for a mobile app that does some cpu intensive work.  We anticipate the app will not have heavy usage most of the time, but will have occasional spikes of high demand.  I was thinking what we should do is reserve a couple of 24/7 servers to handle the steady-state of low demand traffic and then add and remove EC2 instances as needed to handle the spikes.  The mobile app will first hit a simple load balancing server that does a simple round-robin user distribution among all the available processing servers.  The load balancer will handle bringing new EC2 instances up and turning them back off as needed.

Some questions:

I've never written something like this before, does this sound like a good strategy?

What's the best way to handle bringing new EC2 instances up and back down?  I was thinking I could just create X instances ahead of time, set them up as needed (install software, etc), and then stop each instance.  The load balancer will then start and stop the instances as needed (eg through [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto/)).  I think this should be a lot faster and easier than trying to create new instances and install everything through a script or something.  Good idea?

One thing I'm concerned about here is the cost of turning EC2 instances off and back on again.  I looked at the AWS Usage Report and had difficulty interpreting it.  I could see starting a stopped instance being a potentially costly operation.  But it seems like since I'm just starting a stopped instance rather than provisioning a new one from scratch it shouldn't be too bad.  Does that sound right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very reasonable strategy.  I used it successfully before.

You may want to look at [Elastic Load Balancing](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) (ELB) in combination with [Auto Scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/).  Conceptually the two should solve this exact problem.

Back when I did this around 2010, ELB had some problems with certain types of HTTP requests that prevented us from using it.  I understand those issues are resolved.

Since ELB was not an option, we manually launched instances from EBS snapshots as needed and manually added them to an NGinX load balancer.  That certainly could have been automated using the AWS APIs, but our peaks were so predictable (end of month) that we just tasked someone to spin up the new instances and didn't get around to automating the task.

When an instance is stopped, I believe the only cost that you pay is for the EBS storage backing the instance and its data.  Unless your instances have a huge amount of data associated, the EBS storage charge should be minimal.  Perhaps things have changed since I last used AWS, but I would be surprised if this changed much if at all.

Comment: Just to add some more information regarding the original post. When you use the Auto Scaling you will not be stopping and starting servers you will be launching and terminating. The difference is that none of your data on the servers will be saved and there is no cost for the EBS storage because it doesn't exist. If you have EBS Volumes other than the root device attached depending on the configuration those could be left up after the instances are terminated.

Answer (score 1):

First with regards to costs, whether an instance is started from scratch or from a stopped state has no impact on cost.  You are billed for the amount of compute units you use over time, period.

Second, what you are looking to do is called autoscaling. What you do is setup up a launch config that specifies an AMI you are going to use (along with any user-data configs you are using, the ELB and availiabilty zones you are going to use, min and max number of instances, etc. You set up a scaling group using that launch config.  Then you set up scaling policies to determine what scaling actions are going to be attached to the group. You then attach cloud watch alarms to each of those policies to trigger the scaling actions.

You don't have servers in reserve that you attach to the ELB or anything like that.  Everything is based on creating a single AMI that is used as the template for the servers you need.

You should read up on autoscaling at the link below:

http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/

Comment: If you stop an instance, you still pay for the storage that backs that instance (last I checked).

Comment: @EricJ. Yes you certainly would have to pay for the storage, I was just really talking only about the EC2 usage where the act of starting/stopping doesn't have any prices impact in and of itself other than the associated usage time charges.